# Using Response.ContentType="Application/pdf"

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

Is it possible to output a pdf on the fly using:

```
Response.ContentType="Application/pdf"
```

I have a table full of php variables that I want to output in the pdf using the method above. How would I create the pdf when the user clicks a button on the website and display the content from the table?

UPDATE:
Using html2pdf I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/medilogi/public_html/v1/wp-content/themes/default/header.php:8) in /home/medilogi/public_html/v1/wp-content/themes/default/html2pdf/_tcpdf_5.0.002/tcpdf.php on line 6122
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

<?php
$content = "test";

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output('example.pdf');
?>
```

Comment: So you want to use PHP to output a non-existing file with ASP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the pdf before. This response is used only from browser to parse the content type (open directly the PDF using your PDF reader instead of download it).

You can use html2pdf or [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/). Last year I used xslt and apache fop.

Comment: I'm getting the following error (see updated question) with html2pdf.

Comment: I've updated my question. If it helps I'm using wordpress as well.

Comment: take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530183/fatal-error-using-fpdfsome-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf-file

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a pdf generation library like FPDF ([FPDF Website](http://www.fpdf.org/)) or Zend_Pdf (Part of the Zend Framework) to generate your pdf. Please note you set correct headers for Content-Type and Content-Dispostion.